# Comic book where giant alien creature is explored underground

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, graphic-novel

The comic is about a group of scientists exploring a cavern filled with strange neonish colored bugs. They eventually figure out the cavern and creatures are parts of a giant alien creature that is absorbing them into itself. One of them becomes a brain person, and I think one of them has a missing daughter? Please help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: Someone has attempted to edit this question to state that the art style looked post-2000. If that person is you, and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the old one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). In doing so, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from others, leave comments within this thread, and mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if one is posted.

Comment: sound a bit like "Mystery Flesh Pit National Park", but that's more mockumentation than comic

Comment: I reposted an "answer" with someone saying they're looking for the same story, with photographed pages, at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278626/what-is-this-comic-book-involving-people-exploring-a-cave-which-turns-out-to-be to see if it garners any answers.

Answer (score 5):

This might be *Mare Internum*, by Der-shing Helmer.

[The webcomic is complete and available online here.](https://www.marecomic.com/)

Two astronauts fall into a cavern on Mars while trying to track down their lost rover.  They find some crazy life forms, including one that claims it's the rover.

Mike, whose mental state is not great, ends up with multiple foreign ... attachments, so it does look like he's being assimilated. Bex, the other astronaut, has a husband and daughter back on Earth, but came as a permanent colonist so there's some discussion on that.

Answer (score 2):

[Robin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/167235/robin) posted some pictures of a comic book they read with a similar premise, which was identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278626/what-is-this-comic-book-involving-people-exploring-a-cave-which-turns-out-to-be/278629?noredirect=1#comment768571_278629) as being Image Comics's *[Unearth](https://imagecomics.com/comics/releases/unearth-1)*.

[image: Cover of Unearth #1]

> When a flesh-warping disease ravages a remote village in Mexico, a scientific task force travels to the inhospitable area to investigate the contamination. Tracing the source of the disease to a nearby cave system, the team discovers a bizarre, hostile ecosystem and a supernatural revelation from which they may never escape.

The cover of issue #5 looks like it could be depicting your "brain person".

[image: Front cover of Unearth #5]