# What is this comic book involving people exploring a cave which turns out to be a creature, which is transforming the explorers?

Tags: story-identification, comics

This was posted as an answer to [Comic book where giant alien creature is explored underground](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/278068/comic-book-where-giant-alien-creature-is-explored-underground), but got removed since it was basically its own question. I think it's worthwhile to try to find, and the person posted images which could be verified.

### Page 1

[image: Photograph of comic book page where two people discuss how the cave is mutating the explorers] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

### Page 2

[image: Photograph of comic book page showing someone mid-transformation begging to be killed] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

They apparently read it at a library. Three characters are visible in the provided pages. There is an auburn-haired Caucasian man with short hair and a thick mustache who is addressed as King who is speaking to an unnamed auburn-haired Caucasian woman with a spiky ponytail, and in the second page, a man named Rodriguez looks Caucasian with brown hair, but is being disassembled by the creature.

I attempted some image searches for the panels, but only came up with similarly colored comics that have a different art style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Unearth](https://imagecomics.com/comics/releases/unearth-1), an Image Comics production

> When a flesh-warping disease ravages a remote village in Mexico, a
> scientific task force travels to the inhospitable area to investigate
> the contamination. As victims of the illness are transformed in
> horrible ways, the task force traces the source of the disease to a
> nearby cave system—where they discover a bizarre, hostile ecosystem
> and a supernatural revelation from which they may never escape

[image]

Comment: Do you think that would match the other question? I don't know if that would count for the "neon bugs".

Comment: I think it matches pretty good @FuzzyBoots based on the not-answer comments.  Better match than mine.